# Injecting code and spawning MCs in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i'm porting my game from as2 to as3 and i'm stuck trying to figure how to make the enemies work,so on as2 i had enemies as MCs and i had code on then,but now that i'm coding on the main frame time line i don't know how to make many enemies spawn each using the same code.
I tried looking into classes,but still could not make it work.So my question is: how do i spawn many MCs and inject code on them on as3?

help will be much apreciated i'm trying all day long to make it work.

Comment: If  you look at your enemy MC in the library, right click and choose 'edit class,' you could then put code in their constructor function. This code will then be automatically executed whenever an instance of them is created. You could also create other functions in there if you wish.

Comment: Alternatively you can add your MC instances to an array as you create them, then loop through the array to execute certain code on each of them.

Comment: thanks a lot,i will try it

Comment: it worked like a charm,thanks man :D